# Selection of voltage transformer and current transformer for protection in substation

Tags: transformer, relay

having a 66/11 kV substation, how does one know which voltage transformer and current transformer to use? They secondary side would be connected to a distance relay for monitoring. I know they need to withstand the maximum continuous current and a fault current of 31.5kA. I also know that we need to consider the burden on the secondary side, what I dont know is the following:

- turns ratio
- secondary cores and windings

Updated:

[image: primary winding and cores with secondary winding]

[image]

Comment: You're talking over 2 GW.

Comment: ?? Its a 10MVA main transformer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We typically size CTs so at bank full load they have less than 5A in secondary (for 5A CTs like used in U.S.).

Full load current on 66 kV side of your 10 MVA bank is,

$$I_H= 1000\frac{10}{\sqrt{3}\times66}= 87.5 A$$

So, a \$600:5\$ CT would suffice.

Full load current on 11 kV side is,

$$I_L= 1000\frac{10}{\sqrt{3}\times11}= 525 A$$

So, a \$3000:5\$ CT would work.

You usually select the VTs to provide 115 V secondary ph-ph or whatever your protective relays/ instruments want.

**EDIT**: To show utility grade multi-ratio bushing CT.  One core, multiple taps. Only one pair of taps used at a time. The primary conductor goes through center of core.

[image: CT]

Comment: Thanks! This example is in europe with frequency 50Hz and with secondary xxx/1A. I was thinking of using a CT of 800/1. Is it correctly understood that at full load (87.5A) and with a 800/1A CT, the secondary current would be 87.5A/800 = 10mA? My furhter confusion arises when having to use two cores for the secondary, one core for metering and other core for protection. How would I know which secondary currents to use for each core?

Comment: So a CT only has 1 core.  If you have 2 cores you have two CTs.  Also, if you are actually designing a substation for someone you need to reach out to experienced engineers who do this for a living.

Comment: It is very normal for a CT two have two or three secondary cores. One for core for a transducer and another core for relay, as an example.

Comment: Can you send example of utility protection class CT with multiple cores?  Do you really mean multiple taps?

Comment: I have updated my original comment with a picture of the inside part of a CT with the conductor through each core and the secondary cores. Reason for having different cores as I mentioned is for metering and relay. Each core have their own individual class rating and saturation point.

Comment: That’s a very interesting arrangement. Also, those are three different CTs.  Three individual 2-winding transformers.  A single primary winding and a single secondary winding for each. Not a primary winding and multiple secondaries.  Agree?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by three different CTs. In a substation you would have one instrumental current transformer and voltage transformer for each phase. This would be the same type of transformer across All phases. When ordering a CT for ONE phase, you need to specify the ratio and number of cores and each cores accuracy class. The accuracy class for a metering core would usually need to be more precise than the relay core and have different saturation points. The naming of such cores could be 400A/5A/1A as an example. One cores secondary is 5A and the other 1A with different core class

Comment: That is also why you cannot use multi taps since the cores need to be different.

Comment: Hi @JamesW, this whole thread has been me disagreeing with your comment, "It is very normal for a CT two have two or three secondary cores".  You still haven't shown a single CT that has more than 1 core.  The picture you added to your question shows 3 different CTs, each with 1 core (around which the secondary winding of each is wrapped).  Answer this question and it may help clarify, "Are you describing a single current transformer that has more than 1 secondary winding?"  We may just have our terminology confused.

Comment: I am describing a single phase CT with multiple cores. I have added another picture. Here is shown three CTs and each one of those CT could look like the first picture from the inside, that is one single CT can have multiple cores.

Comment: @JamesW I'm pretty sure that picture shows three current transformers. If each of the units in the second picture contains what the first picture shows, then each of those is three current transformers, not one.

Comment: So if each unit contains what the first picture shows, how many current transformers would you say there are?

Comment: @JamesW I'd say nine.

Comment: Then I must say that your initial statement is wrong, or you would be buying 6 current transformers too  many. This is a connection between two long distance substations. Inside the substation itself you have the grid seperator, VT and CT, circuit breaker, another bus bar seperator and then main transformer to step doen the voltage, and each connection per substation must contain 1 current and 1 voltage transformer per phase, that is a total of three current transformer with first picture configuration.

Comment: @JamesW Why are you so insistent on this? I don't know *why* there are three CTs in that module, but there are definitely three of them there.

Comment: First picture is a configuration for a single CT (or atleast single unit) , but lets leave it here. My original question was about the selection of the CT, which i have gained greater understanding by studying substations and by talking with mere experienced electrical engineers than myself. Thank you for taking your time to comment.

Comment: @JamesW 1st picture shows 3 cores (through which 1 primary conductor is passed). Agree?  2nd picture shows 3 free-standing CTs (most likely due to live-tank breakers) which is simply 3 individual CTs with 1 secondary (multi-tapped, but only 1 winding).  You still haven't shown a CT with more than 1 secondary.

Comment: @JamesW  No need to leave it here if you have a real 3-winding CT to show us.  But totally fine to stop discussing of course.  I'm just hoping to learn something I didn't know - which is purpose of this forum.

Comment: Maybe we can Come to a better understanding together if you would explain how you could use one of the units in the second picture to feed a distance relay and transducer/metering at the same time. How would a simple schematic look like? You cant use multi tap because of the accuracy class that need to be different. Hope you understand what I Mean, Else i Will Edit My original post in the upcoming days with some schematics and examples. (Also probably not be using a phone when commenting)

Comment: Yes, you would have six CTs.  3 for relays and 3 for metering.  Your second picture is of free standing CTs.  Their may be more than one CT per phase - can’t tell from a picture.  On dead-tank breakers we use slip over bushing CTs like the picture I show in my answer.  You typically have 2 or 3 CTs per phase. So, you would have 2 or 3 of those on each of the phase bushings.

Comment: So you have multiple CTs in one of those units in the second picture?

Comment: Yes, you will have one core per CT needed. You can have 3-4 CTs in that guy.

Comment: Well that makes sense then. I was always referring to a CT as "that Guy" which would technically be incorrect since "that guy" is just some housing which can container multiple CTs. Probably had it confused when i saw some ordering of CTs and the manufacturer only wanted to know the specifications of the cores. So i would say 3 CT with x specifications. But saying three housings with x CTs in one housing with x core specifications would be more correct, rigt?

Comment: Glad you got it. Yes, you are correct.  They will also tell you how many CTs they can fit in that guy.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to clarify! (Altho would have been cool if a CT had multiple secondary cores, not today i guess :) )